# ボタンを押した時端末の設定画面へ移動させたい

Tags: monaca, cordova

今、monacaでハイブリッドアプリを開発しております。

質問したい内容は、ボタンを押した時端末の設定画面に移動させる、
具体的には現在の画面でボタンを押すとAndroidやiosのネットワークや位置情報同意、アプリケーションの管理などをしている設定画面に移動したいんです。
Androidとios両方とも支援したいので、どっちも設定画面へ移動できるサンプルコードとかがあったら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score -1):

Androidの方はこちらでいいと思います
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:jp.takesi.sample"));
startActivity(intent);